# JqueryCalendar check out date should be auto filled by one week as soon as we select the check in date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am implementing a calendar datepicker for inputting two dates i.e. Check In date and Check Out date.Here By default the check in date should be of today's date and the check out date should be 1 week from now. As soon as we select the date in check in, it should auto filled the date in check out placeholder.

I am using jquery: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker
where they suggest something like this:

```
    $( "#checkOut" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: +7 })
```

but it didn't work for me.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can also refer this jquery plugin for your query http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: @ Ricky... I need two input text box as for check in and check out. if i select the check in date, the check out field should be auto filled with the date 1 week from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this fiddle, [Modified version]

http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/xqqowyvn/

```
$("#FromDate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $("#ToDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('m/d/yy', new Date(new Date(dateText).getTime() + 7*24*60*60*1000)));
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({"defaultDate":dateText});
    }
});
$("#ToDate").datepicker();

<input  id="FromDate" />
<input id="ToDate" />
```

Comment: @ Vijayakumar Selvaraj... Actually, I need two input text box as for check in and check out. if i select the check in date, the check out field should be auto filled with the date 1 week from now.

Comment: added modified version with Jsfiddle

Comment: thanks but i need to have the calendar initialised with the new generated date in the check out field. and if i click on this text box the calendar should be shown with this generated date as selected.

Comment: OK. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/xqqowyvn/1/ this is what u expected?

Comment: thanks a lot...... @ Vijayakumar Selvaraj. It's worked fine. Now my  requirement is to make unselectable dates for check out calendar upto the date selected in check in.